# Framework not found error when using Cocoapods in a framework inside parent project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, subproject

I have a MyApp.xcodeworkspace that uses a homegrown MyAppKit iOS framework. 
MyAppKit is included as xcodeproject inside the parent MyApp project.

When I include Firebases and Google Tag Manager via Cocoapods in MyAppKit framework and compile the parent project, I get this error.

`ld: framework not found Pods_MyAppKit`

and a bunch of warnings:-

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/this.user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
```

**Background...**

Came the need to import Firebase and Google Tag Manager as Cocoapods in MyAppKit framework.

I've done the required `pod init`, `pod install` in MyAppKit without any errors.

MyAppKit.xcworkspace on its own builds and compiles successfully.

The Podfile in MyAppKit looks like this:-

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyAppKit' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyAppKit
        pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.19'
        pod 'Firebase/ABTesting'
        pod 'Firebase/Performance'
        pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
        pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
        pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 7.1'
        pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
end
```

I expect there to be minimal changes to the parent project and ideally don't want to include the same Pods (as in the framework MyAppKit) in the main project as well.

Is there anything incorrect in the way I'm including the Pods in MyAppKit framework.

Is there something additional that I need to do in my parent project MyApp to make this work ?

Thanks,
Tas

Comment: **Pods Environment**
```
   CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
       Xcode : 10.1 (10B61)
         Git : git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/tasvir.rohila/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 7c9a708dce25221eabc35ed39a92524c61ac9ac2
```

Comment: I guess the question here is, how to integrate Pods in a Framework and then use that Framework (along with it's dependencies) in the main project.

Comment: did you make any progress on this?